# Assign variable with distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, user-defined-functions

I have created a Table-Valued function to return a comma seperated list, but am having problems in the list to contain only distinct values.  My function is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[clientContactsConcat] ( @clnum INT )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @concat NVARCHAR(4000)
    SELECT @concat =COALESCE(@concat, ' ') + clcontact + ', '
    FROM    dbo.client
    WHERE crelated = @clnum
    AND NOT clcontact IS NULL
    SELECT  @concat = SUBSTRING(@concat, 2, LEN(@concat) - 2)
    RETURN ( @concat )
END
```

This will currently list all values, when I add modify the SELECT to `SELECT DISTINCT @concat =COALESCE(@concat, ' ') + clcontact + ', '...` then it will only return the first result returned by the select.

Is there any way to return only the distinct records when assigning to a variable in conjunction with the COALESCE?

For the following records:

```
clcontact
---------------------
Mr S Smith
Mrs R Jones
Ms L Morrison
Mrs R Jones
```

I am wanting the following to be returned: `Mr S Smith, Mrs R Jones, Ms L Morrison`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try putting the `SELECT DISTINCT` into a derived table.

```
 SELECT @concat =COALESCE(@concat, ' ') +  clcontact
 FROM
 (

    SELECT DISTINCT  clcontact + ', ' AS clcontact
    FROM    dbo.client
    WHERE crelated = @clnum
    AND NOT clcontact IS NULL
  ) T
```

Note that this method of concatenating strings [is not guaranteed to work](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515/en-us) but I'm not sure of any obviously better way in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Great work, I wasn't sure if I should use a sub-query and in any event wasn't quite sure how to implement it.  Thanks heaps, works like a charm.